# Is there any way for XCode 7 to warn about new API calls?

Tags: ios, xcode7, availability

On more than one occasion I've seen crashing bugs appear on iOS 7.x due to use of a new call that was introduced in 8.x without proper checking.
Is there a way for XCode7 to warn about classes, methods and procedures that are only available a later version than the deployment target?
That way I could easily list through all the code and make sure it's properly conditionalized.

than I search for a solution https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation  but not work since xcode import  modules.  Is there any way for XCode 7 to warn about new API calls ?

Comment: Xcode has no support for this. Look at AppCode from IntelliJ. I believe they support this obvious feature that Apple should be ashamed of for not supporting.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe you wanted to mention AppCode from JetBrains. IntelliJ is totally different IDE :)

Comment: @JulianKról Yes, you are correct. Old habit from way back when JetBrains essentially was IntelliJ.

Comment: As far as I remember the code that is available for later versions than the base sdk they cross it, anyway you would have to look through all the files which I suppose is not convenient. Do not remember if you get warnings there while building but I think so. Worth to check on your own :)